# formatting username

Tags: linux, useradd

While adding a user what the best practice for username?

```
firstname.lastname
first character of firstname.lastname
firstname
lastname
firstnamelastname
```

I prefer "shantanu" from the following list. The sys admin says "shantanu.sharma" is the policy.

```
shantanu.sharma
ssharma
shantanu
sharma
shantanusharma
```

What is the standard practice?

Answer (score 1):

"Best practice" is to follow company policy, rather than argue with it. As for the creation of a policy, there is no standard. There are a few common ideas but most are created out of a combination of what is practical and sensible for a specific situation.

e.g. My users all have their first name as their logon ID. That clearly won't work for most companies, so the many variations of first name and last name, or the initials thereof, are generally used.

Comment: +1 for "there is no standard."  first initial followed by last name (as per the other answer) is very common, but not standard by any means.

Answer (score 0):

In a business sense, and if there a lot of users, first initial then last name. Not dots.

jkerry or gbush or bobama or such.